# How can I remove duplicates from an array list using two methods?

Tags: java

The first method finds the duplicate and the second removes it. 
I tried the following code and it does not work. I don't understand why. to be done using two methods. When I call the methods, they do not remove the duplicates. The arraylist is unchanged. I want to remove the duplicates using two methods.

```
public static int find(ArrayList<String> s, int i) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < s.size(); j = j + 1) {
        if (s.get(i) == s.get(j)) {
            return j;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}


public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i = i + 1) {
        int foundAt = (find(s, i));
        if (foundAt >= 0) {
            s.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason of not using `Set` ?

Comment: Instead of `s.get(i) == s.get(j)` use `s.get(i).equals(s.get(j))`

Answer (score 1):

Don't be bothered:

```
public static List<String> removeDups(final List<String> orig)
{
    return new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(orig));
}
```

(note the use of `LinkedHashSet`, we want to preserve element iteration ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply dump it in a Set

```
List<String> listduplicates =  new ArrayList<String>(10);
//add elements to the list
Set<String> as = new HashSet<String>(listduplicates );

List<String> listunique =  new ArrayList<String>(as.size());
```

listunique now give unique elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with two methods, and following your same idea, you could fix your methods to be:

```
   public static int find(List<String> s, int j) {
        for(int i=j;i<s.size();i++) {
            if (s.lastIndexOf(s.get(i)) != i)  {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> s) {
        for (int j=0; j<s.size();j++) {
            int i = -1;
            while((i=find(s,j))>=0) {
                s.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can use the Stream API with the `distinct()` operation to eleminate duplicates:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6);
List<Integer> filtered = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("filtered: " + filtered); // [5, 3, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it runs fine and removes duplictaes from the list. You may change removeDuplicates method to remove duplicates that come later in the list.

```
 public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i = i + 1) {
                int foundAt = (find(s, i));
                if (foundAt >= 0) {
                    s.remove(foundAt);
                }
            }
        }
```